# Using Session to Pass Data from php to another page

Tags: php, html

I know this has been asked many, many, many times; however, the various things I have seen and tried have not worked.

All I want to do is pass data from one page to the next, so I can use the user's email to do various Database things.

Here's my login.php file (abridged, only showing the login stuff) :

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;

$password = $_POST['user_password'];

//DB stuff

if ($num_results == 1) {

header('Location: nextPage.html');
exit;
}

else {

echo "<p> Username or Password is incorrect! </p>";
}
?>
```

Here is my next page html file:

```
<?php
session_start();

ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

echo $email;
?>


<html>
<head>
<title> next page </title>
</head>

<body>

You have logged in!
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I try to echo the email it is blank, and when I test for it, it tells me that it is empty.

Any advice would be helpful, thanks so much!!

Comment: try renaming nextpage.html to nextpage.php

Comment: also its good practice to check if $_POST values are actually set before using.

Comment: The post values are set and getting checked, sorry I abridged the code, forgot to put that part in. 

@Tushar, is there any specific reason why the next page would need to be php instead of html?

Comment: That worked (changing it to .php), thanks so much!!!!
I would love to know why, though :p

Comment: actuall if you wont mention the extention the browser wont understand where its a scripting language or not

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are having problems is that your `header('Location: nextPage.html');` is pointing to an `.html` file.

Passing sessions from one page to another will only work under a PHP environment and should have been set as `header('Location: nextPage.php');`

However, `.html` files can run as PHP by using the following directives in `.htaccess`

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If you only plan on including the PHP on one page, it is better to setup this way:

```
<Files nextPage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```